# controlling the output with RApacheOutputErrors

Tags: r, rapache

I have activated ROutputErrors in r.conf and it works as is suppose to 
do.

When I have an error I get this:

```
Oops!!! rApache has something to tell you. View source and read the 
HTML comments at the end.
```

And in the source code I get the error.

```
\n<!--\nError in library(micEconAids) : there is no package called 
'micEconAids'\nTraceback:\n5: stop(txt, domain = NA)\n4: 
library(micEconAids)\n3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)\n2: eval(i, envir) 
\n1: sys.source(file = \"\/var\/www\/r\/test\/25.R\", envir = .rAenv) 
\n-->\n
```

I am trying to build a webservice and I would like to have the errors 
directly. I am trying to do this in r.conf

```
RApacheOutputErrors(TRUE,"<p>","</p>")
```

But I get this error on restart:

```
"Invalid command 
'RApacheOutputErrors(TRUE,"<p>","</p>")', perhaps misspelled or 
defined by a module not included in the server configuration";
```

How and where can I use this directive?

Thanks

Comment: You can sit here and wait until Jeff swings by, or, if you get bored, you could ask on the [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/rapache?pli=1) list.

Comment: Here is the discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#topic/rapache/ixDT2mgulRU

Comment: did you check http://rapache.net/manual.html ? I don't know much about this, but there might be a reason they it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

RApacheOutputErrors()
This function has been deprecated and will be removed from the next rApache release. It invokes a warning if it is called.

ref:
 http://rapache.net/manual.html#rapache_Functions

Comment: as you see this is a post from 2010. Just removing the feature still does not remove the initial problem. There will still be a need for proper debugging messages.